# "Why should we pick you as staff?" vs. "Why should we pick you for staff?"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

1. Why should we pick you **[as]** staff?
2. Why should we pick you **[for]** staff?

Which of the above sentences would be correct? Should "as" or "for" be used with the meaning "to be a member of"?

Context: it's for a job interview.

Comment: I have given this some thought over time. While the 'for' is the better form, if you are using this stock question on a job interview, you may be missing its many negative nuances. The canned question invites canned answers meant to flatter you, but not meaningful. The question may seek information but it also challenges, and interviews are already stressful. 'Pick you' matches what you do at the pet store or butcher, not really respectful of your honored guest.

Comment: It's for a job interview.

Answer (score 1):

"For" is the correct choice here (you pick someone *for* a team, not *as* a team), however, I think the phrasing of "Why should we pick you for staff" is awkward.

I'd recommend something more like:

- Why should we bring you onto the team?
- What makes you the right fit for our team?
- Do you think you'd fit in as a member of our staff?

Comment: Hi, Mako212. Your answer contains some good points but would be improved by adding references.